# Prove by induction that $a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{n})n}{2}, \forall n\in \mathbb N$

Tags: induction

### Prove by induction that $$a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{n})n}{2}, \forall n\in \mathbb N$$

**HINT:** Supose that: $a_{i+1}-a_{i}= r, \forall i\in \mathbb N$

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition we want to prov, ie: $a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{n}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{n})n}{2}, \forall n\in \mathbb N$

For $P(1)$ we have:$a_{1}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{1})1}{2} \implies a_{1}=\dfrac{2a_{1}}{2} \implies a_{1}=a_{1}$, so $P(1)$ is true.

For $P(2)$ we have:$a_{1}+a_{2}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{2})2}{2} \implies a_{1}+a_{2}=a_{1}+a_{2} $, so $P(2)$ is true.

**Inductive Hypothesis:** Let $n=k$ and we assume that $$P(k):=a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{K}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{k})k}{2}$$ is true.

**Inductive Step:**

$$a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{k}+a_{k+1}=\dfrac{(a_{1}+a_{k})k}{2}+a_{k+1}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}[(a_{1}+a_{k})k+2a_{k+1}]$$ Using the HINT, $a_{i+1}-a_{i}= r \implies $$a_{k}=a_{k+1}-r$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}[(a_{1}+a_{k})k+2a_{k+1}]=\dfrac{1}{2}[(a_{1}+a_{k+1}-r)k+2a_{k+1}]$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2}(ka_{1}+ka_{k+1}-kr+2a_{k+1})$$

How can i finish this?

Comment: Is the hint an actual hyphothesis?

Comment: It seems to be you mean the sequence $\;a_1,a_2,...\;$ is an **arithmetic sequence** , otherwise the claim is false, of course. For example, $\;1+3+4\neq\frac{(1+4)3}2\;$ ... This *must* be added in to the given data.

Comment: Also I noticed that in your solutions you always check the value of $P(2)$; in most cases it is not necessary

Comment: The arithmetic series condition must be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are given an arithmetic series. You can finish it by realizing that $a_{k + 1} = a_1 + kr$ (although it is obvious, proving *this* rigorously takes a quick use of induction again). Replace one of the $a_{k + 1}$ using this expression. Continuing from where you left, you will get the following
$$
= \frac{1}{2}(ka_1 + ka_{k + 1} - kr + 2a_{k + 1}) \\
= \frac{1}{2}(ka_1 + ka_{k + 1} - kr + a_{k + 1} + (a_1 + kr)) \\
= \frac{1}{2}(a_1(k + 1) + a_{k + 1}(k + 1)) \\
= \frac{(a_1 + a_{k + 1})(k + 1)}{2}.
$$